# Why am I receiving "ERROR [4/5] WORKDIR /server: not a directory" when I copy my proj file to this directory one step before

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to write a simple Dockerfile for my asp.net 6 api:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY Tetris.Blazor/Server/Tetris.Blazor.Server.csproj /server
WORKDIR /server
RUN dotnet restore Tetris.Blazor.Server.csproj
```

But it doesn't work because `mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ivovep5yi409yr2m4g2itm5as/merged/server: not a directory`.
I use linux containers, trying to build it in vs2022.

I expect that after `COPY Tetris.Blazor/Server/Tetris.Blazor.Server.csproj /server` step there should be non-empty directory with my proj file inside, so I can set my workdir to it and run my restore cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have

```
COPY Tetris.Blazor/Server/Tetris.Blazor.Server.csproj /server
```

Docker copies your csproj file into a *file* in the image called `server` in the root directory. When you then try to set your work directory to `/server` it says that it can't do that because `/server` is a file and not a directory.

To copy your csproj file into a *directory* called `/server`, you need to end the name with a slash, so your Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY Tetris.Blazor/Server/Tetris.Blazor.Server.csproj /server/
WORKDIR /server
RUN dotnet restore Tetris.Blazor.Server.csproj
```